# Steam problem with 32bit lib

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit, laptop, steam

After the installation it ask me this

```
Steam needs to install these additional packages: 
    libgl1-mesa-dri:i386, libgl1-mesa-glx:i386, libc6:i386
[sudo] password for giacomo:
```

I insert the password and...

```
..........................................................................................
Lettura elenco dei pacchetti... Fatto
Generazione albero delle dipendenze       
Lettura informazioni sullo stato... Fatto
Alcuni pacchetti non possono essere installati. Questo può voler dire
che è stata richiesta una situazione impossibile oppure, se si sta
usando una distribuzione in sviluppo, che alcuni pacchetti richiesti
non sono ancora stati creati o sono stati rimossi da Incoming.
Le seguenti informazioni possono aiutare a risolvere la situazione:

I seguenti pacchetti hanno dipendenze non soddisfatte:
 indicator-bluetooth : Dipende: bluez (>= 4.36)
                       Dipende: unity-control-center ma non sta per essere installato oppure
                                gnome-control-center ma non sta per essere installato oppure
                                ubuntu-system-settings ma non sta per essere installato
                       Dipende: gnome-bluetooth ma non sta per essere installato oppure
                                ubuntu-system-settings ma non sta per essere installato
 libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 : Dipende: libudev1:i386 ma non sta per essere installato oppure
                                 libudev0:i386 ma non è installabile
 libqt5feedback5 : Dipende: libqt5multimedia5 (>= 5.0.2) ma non sta per essere installato
E: Errore, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve ha generato delle interruzioni. Questo potrebbe essere causato da pacchetti bloccati.
Press return to continue:
```

What i can do?

Comment: Please reun the command again with `LC_ALL=C` before the command to get english messages, and edit the question.

Comment: sorry ahahahahah

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried first to autoremove ? 
Looks like you have a dependency problem, I would run the following commands :

```
sudo apt-get autoremove && sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade -y
```

I'm sure you'll get more help on the way but, that's the first
thing I would do when getting an error as yours.

Comment: Thanks but nothings i had the same problem.